# How to Disconnect these Electrical Connectors?

Tags: electrical, appliances, connectors

How do I disconnect the white electrical connectors? Is there a trick to it or do I simply pull firmly? I don't want to break it. Is there a tab that needs to be pressed? (The appliance is unplugged. It's safe to service.)[image]

Comment: There are latches visible on top of the two wider connectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two of the connectors have retaining clips.

[image]

Lift them up or push them down, whichever will disengage them. Then pull the connector out.

The other connectors might also have some type of retention device, though they're not visible in the photo.